# Does Braintree v.Zero Drop In UI support Apple Pay?

Tags: ios, braintree, applepay

The documentation from Braintree regarding their Drop In UI is pretty limited (does not even mention the v.Zero SDK). I've read that both Android Pay and Apple Pay are supported by the Drop In SDK. Our team had Android Pay working well, but we have not been able to make Apple Pay even appear on the UI.

The question is: Is it possible to use Apple Pay with the Braintree v.Zero Drop In UI or do we have to manually implement it using `PKPaymentButton` and `PKPaymentRequest`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work for Braintree.

The current version of Drop-in does not support Apple Pay as an option. You will need to manually implement it with `PKPaymentButton` and `PKPaymentRequest`.

However, we have a beta version of a major revision to Drop-in that should be rolling out *very* soon, and this will include support for Apple Pay as well as many other improvements. Feel free to reach out if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you for your answer. Any idea how soon? Within July time-frame? August? Q4 2016?  We are launching an app in August and it would be great if we could provide Apple Pay support for our customers from day 1.

Comment: Eneko, it looks like we'll be releasing the beta version tomorrow! We'd love to have you give it a try and let us know what you think. We're hoping to get feedback to make sure we're thinking about the merchant checkout experience the right way -- to support more merchant checkout flows.

Comment: @EnekoAlonso Hi, just a heads up that we've released version 4.4.0 of the iOS SDK, which introduces the new Drop-in with support for Apple Pay. Take a look at [this guide](https://github.braintreeps.com/braintree/braintree-ios/blob/master/Docs/Drop-In-Update.md), and feel free to ping us if you have any questions or feedback/suggestions!

Comment: Thanks, @Richard. I'm downloading the new version now. Seems however that the guide link you pasted required authentication and I have no access.

Comment: Hi @Richard, it seems as if the ApplePay support was removed from the 4.4.0 version a few days ago (see https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/commit/16de5962bedfc343a8a8f6e8508a33ade768aec4), maybe not ready for production? How can I access the Beta version?

Comment: Nevermind, found the docs for the new DropIn UI: https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/master/Docs/Drop-In-Update.md

Comment: @EnekoAlonso D'oh, sorry about that, I linked to our internal GitHub. Glad you found the public version :)